# Remove XML namespaces during XSLT transformation?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to remove the namespace from the input XML and also keep the current processing of elimination of child node and move data to parent node in the XSLT.
Based on various threads, i tried to remove the namespace by defining another namespace but i am unable to get the required output.

The below XSLT code for elimination of child node and move data is working but the code for removal of namespace is not working.

XSLT code -

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:bc="urn:com.matrix/bc"
  xmlns:test="urn:com.matrix/test"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  exclude-result-prefixes="bc test">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="bc:PersonData">     
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="bc:Person"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="bc:Person">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="*/*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input XML -

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <bc:PersonData xmlns:bc="urn:com.matrix/bc">
 <bc:Header>
    <data1>abc</data1>
    <data2>def</data2>
 </bc:Header>
 <bc:Person>
    <bc:Personal>
        <bc:FirstName>abc</bc:FirstName>
        <bc:LastName>cde</bc:LastName>
        <bc:ID>12345</bc:ID>
    </bc:Personal>
    <bc:Address>
        <bc:Address1>abc123</bc:Address1>
        <bc:Address2>def345</bc:Address2>
        <bc:Address3>uyt57</bc:Address3>
    </bc:Address>
    <bc:PhoneData>
        <bc:Phone1>111111111</bc:Phone1>
    </bc:PhoneData>
  </bc:Person>
  </bc:PersonData>
```

Expected Output XML - Without child nodes and namespace

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <PersonData>
 <Person>
    <FirstName>abc</FirstName>
    <LastName>cde</LastName>
    <ID>12345</ID>
    <Address1>abc123</Address1>
    <Address2>def345</Address2>
    <Address3>uyt57</Address3>
    <Phone1>111111111</Phone1>
  </Person>
  </PersonData>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a shorter (20 lines) and more generic solution. Also push-style is used as much as possible:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:bc="urn:com.matrix/bc">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri()]">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*[namespace-uri()]">
     <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="bc:Person/*"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/*/*[not(self::bc:Person)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <bc:PersonData xmlns:bc="urn:com.matrix/bc">
 <bc:Header>
    <data1>abc</data1>
    <data2>def</data2>
 </bc:Header>
 <bc:Person>
    <bc:Personal>
        <bc:FirstName>abc</bc:FirstName>
        <bc:LastName>cde</bc:LastName>
        <bc:ID>12345</bc:ID>
    </bc:Personal>
    <bc:Address>
        <bc:Address1>abc123</bc:Address1>
        <bc:Address2>def345</bc:Address2>
        <bc:Address3>uyt57</bc:Address3>
    </bc:Address>
    <bc:PhoneData>
        <bc:Phone1>111111111</bc:Phone1>
    </bc:PhoneData>
  </bc:Person>
  </bc:PersonData>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<PersonData>
   <Person>
      <FirstName>abc</FirstName>
      <LastName>cde</LastName>
      <ID>12345</ID>
      <Address1>abc123</Address1>
      <Address2>def345</Address2>
      <Address3>uyt57</Address3>
      <Phone1>111111111</Phone1>
   </Person>
</PersonData>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace two `xsl:copy`s with the non-namespaced versions of the associated elements, and replace `xs:copy-of` with `xs:apply-templates` so that your `xs:template/match="*"` can strip the namespaces as designed.

Then this XSLT,

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:bc="urn:com.matrix/bc"
  exclude-result-prefixes="bc">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="bc:PersonData">     
    <PersonData>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="bc:Person"/>
    </PersonData>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="bc:Person">
    <Person>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*"/>
    </Person>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will generate this output XML,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PersonData>
   <Person>
      <FirstName>abc</FirstName>
      <LastName>cde</LastName>
      <ID>12345</ID>
      <Address1>abc123</Address1>
      <Address2>def345</Address2>
      <Address3>uyt57</Address3>
      <Phone1>111111111</Phone1>
   </Person>
</PersonData>
```

as requested.